# Loop on get_object_or_404 stops after a failing a condition

Tags: python, django

I am trying to extract objects from a model based on another model:

**Code**

```
def financials (request):
    finance = list(Quiz.objects.filter(owner=request.user.pk).values_list('id', flat=True))
    print('finance', finance)
    invoice_list = []

    for i in finance:
        print('i',i)

        invoice_object = get_object_or_404(Invoice, invoice_quiz_id=i)
        invoice_list.append(invoice_object)
```

but it stops after a single loop because it does match the condition, any help is appreciated.

This is what I tried:

```
invoice_object = [get_object_or_404(Invoice, invoice_quiz_id=i) for i in finance]
```

How come this loop just stops if it matches a false condition ? How to make it continue of failing the condition?

Comment: How many elements does your `finance` contains?

Comment: It might be more effective to just obtain the `Invoice`s with `Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_quiz__owner=request.user)`

Comment: You should consider using foreing keys and their references instead of creating a list of ids and doing one SQL query on every item.

Comment: I have about 53 items in the list `finance`. I cannot use `request.user` I need to have all the `Invoice`s which have the same ID as in the list `finance`

Comment: @chirag: but you use `request.user`, in your `owner=request.user.pk`.

Comment: The fact thtat it does not match the condition is not per se wrong by the way. It is definitely possible that there is a `Quiz` object, for which there is no `Invoice` object that is pointing towards it.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. @WillemVanOnsem You were talking about the finance list. I am geting all the Id's in the finance list just fine. But will try your method still. Though this does not help my cause I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How come this loop just stops if it matches a false condition ? How to make it continue of failing the condition?

The idea of a [**`get_object_or_404(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), is like the documentation says:

> Calls `get()` on a given model manager, but it **raises `Http404` instead of the model’s `DoesNotExist` exception**.

So by design it will raise an error if no such object exists, or multiple objects exist. If you do not want that, you might want to use [**`.first()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) or [**`.filter(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) instead.

That being said, if you are just interested in `Invoice` objects where the `invoice_quiz` refers to a `Quiz` that has as `owner` `request.user`, you can define a queryset like:

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_quiz__owner=request.user)
```

This is not only more elegant, but more efficient as well, since you will make some `JOIN`s at the database side, and thus fetch all `Invoice` objects in a single query, not in *N+1* queries with *N* the number of `Quiz`zes.